# Conditional steps in BuildBot

Tags: python, buildbot

I'm trying to create a build configuration with BuildBot using conditional steps. In particular, I want to have conditional steps based on whether or not a preceding step failed, something like this:

```
factory = util.BuildFactory()
factory.addStep(MyCoolStep())
factory.addStep(CommitWork(), doStepIf='MyCoolStepWorked')
factory.addStep(RollbackWork(), doStepIf='MyCoolStepFailed')
```

According to the docs, the 'doStepIf' takes a boolean qualifier.  How do I access the result of a preceding step? Or do I need to set a custom property somewhere?  I'm somewhat new to Python, so I'm not sure about the scoping of various variables and objects in the buildbot master config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each step in Buildbot returns as status either `SUCCESS`, `WARNINGS`, `SKIPPED`, `FAILURE`, `CANCELLED`, `EXCEPTION`, `RETRY`

So if `MyCoolStep` worked, it sets the build status to `SUCCESS`, which you can check for `CommitWork` to execute it.

For `RollbackWorkflow` you can check whether the build is in `FAILURE` state and execute it. Since `CommitWork` is skipped in this state, the overall state won't upgrade to `SKIPPED`

Both steps are hidden if `SKIPPED` so they won't pollute the buildbot output when not executed.

```
def success(build):
  return build.getStatus() == SUCCESS

def failure(build):
  return build.getStatus() == FAILURE

def skipped(results, build):
  return results == SKIPPED

factory = util.BuildFactory()
factory.addStep(MyCoolStep())
factory.addStep(CommitWork(), doStepIf=success, hideStepIf=skipped)
factory.addStep(RollbackWork(), doStepIf=failure, hideStepIf=skipped)
```

Comment: Thank you.  The key here is that, within master.cfg, the build.getStatus() call will return the result of the most recent step.  What I ended up doing was coding MyCoolStep to detect the success/failure internally and perform any relevant rollback there, rather than have BuildBot manage it.

Comment: It seems like in a recent buildbot (e.g. 3.5.0) body of `failure(build)` shall be changed: `return build.getStatus() == FAILURE` =>`return build.build.results == FAILURE`