# How do I redo a step in buildbot if it fails?

Tags: buildbot

I stack a few steps in the Factory, and I hope it can redo some of the steps if it fails automatically.But I couldn't find any instance in the docs.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61534795/